# How to make arrows disappear when hitting the ground and not players

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was wondering how to do this because I've been struggling with it the last 2 hours (making a minecraft minigame map).

Comment: You Really need to give more detail, it's not a bad question but you need to specify. Look at some other good questions, it's also good is you show what you tried to do.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 4):

First you will have to scoreboard tag arrows when they are in the ground using `{inGround:1b}`:

```
scoreboard players tag @e[type=arrow] add inGround {inGround:1b}
```

Then you can target them with a kill command:

```
kill @e[tag=inGround]
```

Comment: In 1.13 you'll be able to use an NBT selector in the target selector, which reduces the to one command.